# Accept as a parameter any object with a toString() method

Tags: java, generics, duck-typing

I'm trying to create a method which can accept objects of a variety of types, perform toString on whatever object is passed in, and then print it. Sometimes it will be an int, sometimes a long, sometimes a string, sometimes a custom object, etc. The only assertion should be that it has a toString() method. Basically, I want to simulate python's duck-typing, rather than having to call toString() outside of this API every time I use the method.

This was the existing functionality:

```
/**
 * Log a message at TEST level
 * @param message: The message to log
 */
public void test(String message) {
    log(Level.TEST, message);
}
```

Here's what I have so far in attempting to enhance it:

```
/**
 * Log a message at TEST level
 * @param message: An object of any class that implements toString.
 */
public void test(Class<?> message) {
    String messageString = message.toString();
    log(Level.TEST, messageString);
}
```

This seems syntactically correct, but it doesn't give what I want:

```
Cannot resolve method 'test(int)'
```

Is there a sound way to achieve this functionality in Java?

Comment: That method would work for any type except primitives. And you shouldn't expect it to work either, as primitive types don't have `toString()` method.

Comment: Since primitive types are not object of classes it won't work with them. You can use the Integer class etc...

Comment: @GiladNaaman I tried that as well to no avail. Cannot resolve method 'test(java.lang.Integer)'

Comment: All classes inherit toString from Object and hence all either directly or indirectly "implement" that method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public void test(Object message) {
    log(Level.TEST, message.toString());
}
```

Autoboxing will take care of primitives. Fair warning though: the default output of many (most?) toString() methods isn't very readable, since they defer to the Object.toString() method.

Comment: Hm. The documentation states that "The Java compiler applies autoboxing when a primitive value is ... passed as a parameter to a method that expects an object of the corresponding wrapper class." Apparently that wrapper class expectation must be explicit, as the wildcard isn't resolved. Thanks.

Comment: @Decency That's not your problem. Your problem is that you weren't using generics correctly. Even if you had used generics correctly, using a generic that extends from Object doesn't make any sense. Just use an Object reference.

Answer (score 2):

Any class will have a `toString()` method, because `java.lang.Object` has it. Therefore, your assertion is sort of... pointless.

As @Kevin mentioned, use `Object message` instead of `Class clazz` and that will do it. :)